# Reusable content block

Tags: wp-admin, content

There is a content block that I wish to put on certain pages.

This content block needs to be managed in WordPress. I'm not sure where it should be situated in the admin. It's not really a custom post type, i.e. it doesn't have any sub posts. It's literally just a block that contains a heading, some text and some logos.

I have use of Advanced Custom Fields if this helps and I'm using WordPress with the JSON API.

Comment: If you are using ACF you can add an options page, and then add ACF fields to that page. See -> https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/
You will also want to check how to get values from an options page with ACF -> https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/

Comment: @gdaniel.  Ha.  Good minds think alike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using ACF, create an options page and then add a field there.  Then present that data in a side widget by echoing out the field.

once the field is created you can call it with this code:

```
<?php the_field('page_content', 'option'); ?>
```

I like to add it to a function

```
function rt_show_field() {
    $field = '';
    if (get_field('page_content', 'option')) {
        $field = get_field('page_content', 'option');
    }
  return $field;
}
add_shortcode( 'my-field', 'rt_show_field');
```

Then if you add that function to your functions.php

you can simply add this short code to a widget

```
[my-field]
```

or add the function

```
echo rt_show_field();
```

to a template page or whereever you want.